# Selenium ChomeDriver not identifying XPATH of website's menu button

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pull product assortment breakdowns from fashion retail websites using **selenium chromedriver**. However, I am getting stuck very early on because I cannot select the company's **menu button**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.zara.com/ca/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)


menudd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="theme- 
app"]/div/div/header/div/div[1]/button/svg')
menudd.click()
```

**ERROR:**

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 8>()
  4 driver.get("https://www.zara.com/ca/")
  5 driver.implicitly_wait(5)
----> 8 menudd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="theme- 
app"]/div/div/header/div/div[1]/button/svg')
  9 menudd.click()`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to use `WebDriverWait` expected conditions explicit waits, not `implicitly_wait`.
Also your locator is bad.
This worked for me:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.zara.com/ca/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Open Menu']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to locate svg in xpath, you should write in this way

```
//*[@id="theme-app"]/div/div/header/div/div[1]/button/*[name()='svg']
```